# Consulta erronea a Foursquare?

Tags: python, json, api

He creado esta función para poder hacer consultas a Foursquare y le pido que me devuelva los aeropuertos cerca de esas coordenadas,por qué no me devuelve nada,no tendría que aparecer un json con todos los datos???

````
def getAirportFoursquare():

    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search'
    params = dict(
        Client_Id=os.getenv("clientID"),
        Client_Secret=os.getenv("clientSecret"),
        ll='1.352083,103.819836',
        query="airport",
        
    )
    resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)

    print(data = json.loads(resp.text))```
````

Comment: Preguntaste lo mismo hace dos días atrás. ¿Algún avance?

Comment: ahora si parece que me lo acepta pero cuando hago print no devuelve nada!

Comment: No conozco foursquare, pero normalmente las coordenadas deben indicar latitud (N o S) y longitud (W o E). Probando con longitud W, tienes un punto en la selva de Sumatra (S) o un parque en Singapore (N). Con longitud E, quedas en medio del mar.

Comment: Esas coordenadas son para el downtown de singapur,y están en decimales no tengo que indicar grados ni puntos cardinales

Comment: Estás haciéndole `print()` a la definición de la variable, trata con solo `print(json.loads(resp.text))`